# Generate random number with large upper bound

Tags: python, memory, random

I am trying to generate random numbers in Python over a very large range (e.g., from 1 to $2^80$) but I am getting the following error:

[image]

Any ideas of why this happens or how I can get around it?

Comment: Can I ask why you want to do this?

Comment: I want to compute a form of Shapley value for a set of 80 agents. I am drawing samples from the power set of 2**80, then converting to binary so I can get a random coalition of those agents.

Comment: You could use random.randrange(1, N) instead. Choice is for selecting a random item from a list

Comment: It looks like you're working with NumPy. NumPy has no integer data type large enough to support this range, since common machine architectures provide no support for integers this large. You're going to be stuck using Python object arithmetic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need 1 random number only. In that case, the normal random generator seems fine:

```
import random
print(random.randrange(1, 2**80))
```

If you need a random coalition of Agents, there's no need to get a random number and convert it to binary. Just build the coalition directly by choosing from `True` and `False`:

```
agents = [ ... 80 agents ...]
coalition = []
for i in range(len(agents)):
    if random.choice([True, False]):
        coalition.append(agents[i])
```

For the `replace=False` part, you could remember the drawn numbers as part of the function:

```
def get_coalition(agents: list, replace = False):
    # initialize a method-static variable
    try:
        get_coalition.chosen
    except AttributeError:
        get_coalition.chosen = []

    # select agents and calculate a numeric representation
    coalition = []
    numeric_representation = 0
    for i in range(len(agents)):
        numeric_representation <<= 1
        if random.choice([True, False]):
            coalition.append(Agent())
            numeric_representation += 1

    # redraw if the combination was already chosen
    if not replace:
        if numeric_representation in get_coalition.chosen:
            return get_coalition(agents)
            pass
        else:
            get_coalition.chosen.append(numeric_representation)

    return coalition
```

Comment: Thank you! Both solutions work well numerically, but I actually need to draw a larger sample from the set of coalitions. Is there a way to ensure the draw is done w/o replacement? This is why I used ```choice``` to begin with.

Comment: @MariusAndreiZoican you mean that if you run the method again, it won't produce the same result?

Comment: Exactly. Before I had:

```list_samples = np.random.choice(range(1, 2 ** no_analysts), size=smple, replace=False)``` 
and I replaced it with

```list_samples = [random.randrange(1, 2 ** no_analysts) for x in range(0, smple)]```

Comment: The probabilty to draw the same number twice is extremely small for this range. If you still are concerned, keep a list of your numbers, and call the random function again, if you havd a match

Comment: @MariusAndreiZoican Ok, in that case, remembering the number would be simpler than remembering a combination of Booleans. How many combinations do you need?

Comment: About 2**15 combinations.

Comment: That's not much. Just keep a list of the drawn numbers in memory and re-draw if the number had already been chosen.

Comment: Something like this? 

<code>
    list_samples=[]
    no_samples=0
    while (no_samples<smple):
        x=random.randrange(1, 2 ** no_analysts)
        if not(x in list_samples):
            list_samples.append(x)
            no_samples+=1
</code>

Comment: @MariusAndreiZoican yes, that looks ok.